# First published NPM package returns an empty object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I just tried my hand on publishing a simple react component but when it is imported it returns an empty object?

Package is — react-selekt (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-selekt)

GitHub — https://github.com/mikethehud/react-selekt

```
import React from “react”;
import Selekt from “react-selekt”

console.log(Selekt);
// returns {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because you are building it with webpack. I would just transpile it with babel-cli to common js and that should be it

Also I would recommend to move react dependency to peerDependencies